# Compilation doesn't end when outsourcing tikz standalone file

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files

Here is the code for my Tikz document:

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    % Definition of blocks:
    \tikzset{%
        block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, minimum height = 3em,
            minimum width = 8em, fill=white, text width=2.5cm},
        sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm}, % Adder
        input/.style    = {coordinate}, % Input
        output/.style   = {coordinate}, % Output
        virtual/.style = {coordinate}
    }
    % Defining string as labels of certain blocks.
    \newcommand{\suma}{\Large$+$}
\begin{figure}
    \center

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45]
    \draw
    % Drawing the blocks of first filter :
    node at (0,0){}
    node [input, name=input1] {} 
    node [block, right = 1cm of input1] (inte2) {LDPC Encoder}
        node [block, right = 1cm of inte2] (inte3) {BPSK modulator}
            node [block, right = 1cm of inte3] (inte4) {Intersymbol intereference (ISI)}
    node [sum, right = 1cm of inte4] (suma1) {\suma}
    node [input, name=input2, above = 1cm of suma1] {} 
    node [output, name=output1, right = 1cm of suma1] {};
    \node [block, right = 1cm of output1] (model) {Model};
    \node [block, right = 1.5cm of model] (model1) {Model1};
    \node [virtual, left=of model.165] (input)     {};
    \node [virtual, right=of model1.0] (output)    {};
    \node [virtual, below left=of model.west] (feedback)  {};
    % Joining blocks. 
    % Commands \draw with options like [->] must be written individually
    \draw[->](input1) -- node {$m$}(inte2);
    \draw[->](inte2) -- node {$c$}(inte3);
        \draw[->](inte3) -- node {$x$}(inte4);
            \draw[->](inte4) -- node {$x+h$}(suma1);
    \draw[->](input2) -- node {$w(t)$} (suma1);
    \draw [->] (suma1.30) -- node {$y$} (model.171);
    \draw[->](model) -- node {$q_\Phi(x|y)$} (model1);
    \draw [->] (model1) -- node [name=y] {$p(x)$}(output);
    \draw [->,rounded corners] (model1) -- (y.south) |- (feedback) |- (model.195);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I try to include this in my main file using:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{syshl}%     without .tex extension
    % or use \input{mytikz}
    \caption{My TikZ picture}
    \label{fig:tikz:my}
\end{figure}
```

The Tikz code is in `syshl.tex`.

Thanks

Comment: I see that you have multiple active user-accounts. May be you can ask the `SE` CS to merge them. More importantly, if you think the answers to your pervious questions were useful, consider accepting it. Your user accounts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/180683/bion and https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/180609/bion

Comment: `\newcommand{\suma}{\Large$+$}` means that using `\suma` anywhere would make all following text (for the remainder of the current group, or the whole document) large, is that the intention?

Comment: @David Carlisle yes that was the initial intention from the OP's previous question atleast. However, for this question, I have no idea ;) I just treated this as a follow-up of the previous question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `figure` environment in your `standalone` file and then include the necessary packages in your `main` file and compile it. Then it should work.

For instance:

**Standalone figure file**

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    % Definition of blocks:
    \tikzset{%
        block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, minimum height = 3em,
            minimum width = 8em, fill=white, text width=2.5cm},
        sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm}, % Adder
        input/.style    = {coordinate}, % Input
        output/.style   = {coordinate}, % Output
        virtual/.style = {coordinate}
    }
    % Defining string as labels of certain blocks.
    \newcommand{\suma}{\Large$+$}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45]
        \draw
        % Drawing the blocks of first filter :
        node at (0,0){}
        node [input, name=input1] {} 
        node [block, right = 1cm of input1] (inte2) {LDPC Encoder}
        node [block, right = 1cm of inte2] (inte3) {BPSK modulator}
        node [block, right = 1cm of inte3] (inte4) {Intersymbol intereference (ISI)}
        node [sum, right = 1cm of inte4] (suma1) {\suma}
        node [input, name=input2, above = 1cm of suma1] {} 
        node [output, name=output1, right = 1cm of suma1] {};
        \node [block, right = 1cm of output1] (model) {Model};
        \node [block, right = 1.5cm of model] (model1) {Model1};
        \node [virtual, left=of model.165] (input)     {};
        \node [virtual, right=of model1.0] (output)    {};
        \node [virtual, below left=of model.west] (feedback)  {};
        % Joining blocks. 
        % Commands \draw with options like [->] must be written individually
        \draw[->](input1) -- node {$m$}(inte2);
        \draw[->](inte2) -- node {$c$}(inte3);
        \draw[->](inte3) -- node {$x$}(inte4);
        \draw[->](inte4) -- node {$x+h$}(suma1);
        \draw[->](input2) -- node {$w(t)$} (suma1);
        \draw [->] (suma1.30) -- node {$y$} (model.171);
        \draw[->](model) -- node {$q_\Phi(x|y)$} (model1);
        \draw [->] (model1) -- node [name=y] {$p(x)$}(output);
        \draw [->,rounded corners] (model1) -- (y.south) |- (feedback) |- (model.195);
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and your **main file**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{tikz_se}%     without .tex extension
        % or use \input{mytikz}
        \caption{My TikZ picture}
        \label{fig:tikz:my}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

this would give you:

[image]

PS: I (re)named your `standalone` file as `tikz_se`.